# How to escape ' " and & in Twig

Tags: symfony, csv, twig

I am exporting a CSV file in my Symfony application.

How can I escape symbols: `'`, `"` and `&` in Twig?

The filter `|escape` doesn't work and I am still getting `&#039` etc. in my output file.

Comment: You probably should not be doing that in Twig, you can use Symfonyies StreamingResponse and write the file to 'php://output'. See here https://vauly.com/symfony2-export-csv for an example.

Comment: I already use StreamedResponse and I return a csv file. The issue was that I did not use | raw filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
{{ string | raw }}
```

Please show your Twig code, without it, it's guessing.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks!